# calling a private array from another private array in php

Tags: php, arrays, private

I don't understand why doesn't this code work:

```
<?php
class Test {

    private $BIG = array(
        'a' => 'A',
        'b' => 'B',
        'c' => 'C'
    );

    private $arr2 = array(
        $this->BIG['a'],
        $this->BIG['b'],
        'something'
    );

    public function getArr2(){
        return $this->arr2;
    }


}

$t = new Test();
print_r($t->getArr2());

?>
```

I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_VARIABLE, expecting ')' in
>   /home/web/te/test.php
>   on line 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't combine variables in a class member definition. You can only use native types and constants:

```
private $arr = array('a', 'b');
private $obj = new stdClass(); // error
private $obj = (object)array(); // error
private $num = 4;
private $a = 1;
private $b = 2;
private $c = $this->a + .... // error
```

If you want to combine or calculate, do that in `__construct`:

```
private $a = 1;
private $b = 2;
private $c;

function __construct() {
  $this->c = $this->a + $this->b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference $this when declaring properties.

Answer (score 1):

From the [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> [Property] declaration may include an
>   initialization, but this
>   initialization must be a constant
>   value--that is, it must be able to be
>   evaluated at compile time and **must not
>   depend on run-time information in
>   order to be evaluated**.

Therefore, do actions like that in the constructor:

```
class Test {

    private $BIG = array(
        'a' => 'A',
        'b' => 'B',
        'c' => 'C'
    );

    private $arr2;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->arr2 = array(
            $this->BIG['a'],
            $this->BIG['b'],
            'something'
        );
    }

    public function getArr2(){
        return $this->arr2;
    }
}
```